# NextJS-ReferenceError: Element is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, rollupjs

After I bundled my ReactJS components using rollup.js , I am trying to use with nextjs.
But it gives this error with nextjs:

```
ReferenceError: Element is not defined
```

Here is my `rollup.config.js`

```
const extensions = [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"];

export default {
  input: "./src/index.js",
  output: [
    {
      file: pkg.main,
      format: "cjs",
    },
    {
      file: pkg.module,
      format: "esm",
    },
  ],
  plugins: [
    external(),
    postcss({
      plugins: [
        simplevars(),
        cssvariables(),
        nested(),
        cssnext({ warnForDuplicates: false}),
        cssnano(),
      ],
      extensions: [".css"],
    }),
    babel({
      exclude: "node_modules/**",
      extensions,
    }),
    // Allows node_modules resolution
    resolve({
      mainFields: ["module", "main", "jsnext:main", "browser"],
      extensions,
    }),
    commonjs(),
    image(),
    visualizer(),
  ],
};
```

Normally there is no usage problem in reactjs app. But this happens with nextjs. I assume it is maybe about ssr. But I am not sure.

How can I fix this error?
Is there any needs to change on `rollap.config.js` for eliminating this error?

Thanks

Comment: Have you found the answer to this problem? I met with similar issue

Comment: Still facing this issue. any solution ?